# Cognos 8.3 add style variable to a table cell

Tags: cognos

I can't seem to add Style Variable based on a data item from a query to a cell in a table. Note though that this is just a regular table not a data container like a list etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the process of trying to get an answer for you on this, but I think there is a bug with COGNOS. I created a boolean variable and applied a style to a list report, and everything ran swimmingly. As soon as I tried to apply a style variable to the table cell, it errored out with a variable error.

I'm taking a bit of a guess here, but I think that when you're creating a variable that references a query, the style variables can only be applied to objects which are associated with that same query. That's why a list report might work where a table cell wouldn't. I haven't seen any other information on this either.

Edit: Could you use a singleton within a table cell? That would help. I'm not sure that they are available in 8.3, though.

Comment: Hi Melee, what do you mean by "Could you use a singleton within a table cell?" ?

Comment: Actually what I mean was, I have used a singleton! I defined a query in Query Explorer, then back in Page Explorer I dragged-dropped a table and in one of its cells I dragged-dropped a data item from that query, therefore creating a singleton. 

I'd like to change the background colour of that cell in accordance to a conditional style variable I define based on the value of that singleton... and Cognos won't let me! 

Very aggravating!

Comment: You should be able to resize the singleton to 100% of the table cell width, then use the style variable on that? It'd be worth a try :)